# first fundamental theorem of calculus vs Leibniz rule

Tags: calculus, integration, leibniz-integral-rule

Apostol asks us to check if the equation of

$$y_1 = \int\limits_{c}^x f(x - t)R(t)dt$$

is a particular solution of the differential equation $y'' + ay' + by = R$, s.t. $f(0) = 0, f'(0) = 1$.

The correct solution involves the application of Leibniz rule to $y_1$ to find its derivative. BUT why doesn't the first fundamental theorem of calculus work? Then,

$$\frac{dy_1}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\int\limits_{c}^x f(x - t)R(t)dt = f(x - x)R(x) = 0!$$

which is incorrect. What went wrong here?

Comment: $f$ is a function of both $x$ and $t$. Take a simpler example, $\int_1^x(x-t) \, dt=x \int_1^x 1 dt-\int_1^x t \,dt$ and work it out.

Comment: When integrand and boundaries are functions of parameter, then there holds different formula.